# How can I print out all numbers in a single DialogBox (JOPTION)?

Tags: java, for-loop, fibonacci

```
package Fibonacci;
class Fibonacci 
{
public static void main(String[]args) {
int a = 0;
int b = 1;
    
String input; 
input = javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many elements you want to print in a Fibonacci series");
int n = Integer.parseInt(input);
    

javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, a + " "+ b + " ");
    
int c;

for(int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
       
c = a + b;
        
javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, c + " ");
       
a = b;
b = c;
}
   
}
}
```

// Here is the code ? what can I change to display the output on only one dialogbox? Sorry I'm just new with learning java,

Comment: Do not post images of code. Edit your answer and add text here.

Comment: I already edit it sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first collect the data which you want to print in a DialogBox.
Then you can print the data with the DialogBox (not in the for loop).

Take a look at following code.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class main {

    public static long fibonacci(int n){
        long a = 0, b = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            b = a + (a = b);
        }
        return a;
    }

    public static void main(String... args){

        int input = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Number of print elements"));

        String fib = "";

        for (int i = 0; i <= input; i++) {
            fib = fib + fibonacci(i) + "\n";
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, fib);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you see my code ? I actually tried to print it outside the for loop but it not reading the data inside the loop anymore so I'm not getting my desired output